# Cannot find Console App(.NET Framework) in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0zlU.jpg

I want to start learning C#, I wanted to use Visual Studio and the tutorial I am following from requires me to open up ConsoleApp(.NET Framework) within the New Project section. However, I cannot even see this option or any of the other options for that matter. I'm not sure if my Program is bugged or if I'm just missing something within the installation. When I first started to download it however, an error came up exclaiming that I had I was missing redistributable package c++ or something like that on an unsecure internet connection. I have no idea what any of that meant so I just hit cancel. this also comes up whenever I try to play PUBG.

Comment: What packages did you choose when you installed Visual Studio? Open up the Visual Studio Installer and ensure you checked the .NET Desktop development package

Answer (score 0):

In the screenshot you provided, just hit ok and you will have created a new C# Console App project.

Comment: I do that. When I get into the program, it doesn't allow me to start or run the code that I create. the only thing that appears says attach.

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the .NET development package. Install it using the Visual Studio Installer app.